# How to import qgis.core to python IDLE?

Tags: qgis, python

I try to follow the step in [How to import qgis.core to Python app?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22886/how-to-import-qgis-core-to-python-app) to import qgis.core with Python Shell. But when I type

```
set PYTHONPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\qgis\bin
```

it report

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

and highlight PYTHONPATH

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to import qgis.core to python app?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22886/how-to-import-qgis-core-to-python-app)

Comment: but my qgis.core is locate in C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\qgis\bin not in D:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\qgis\python .I mean not only because in the different drive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that command is not supposed to be typed into python console.

open a windows command prompt and type the command.

Comment: +1 (at least I will once they allow me to vote posts again) Missed it, too.

Comment: which means use cmd??

Comment: @blueman010112 yes

Comment: I tried but still can't I type set PYTHONPATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\qgis\bin and set PYTHONPATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\qgis\bin" but still can't!

Comment: @blueman010112 - ok..what is the error you are getting while typing it in the command prompt?

Comment: @blueman010112 - did you try to run cmd.exe as administrator?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/XeDVM.jpg here's the error and what I do...and I run cmd.exe as admin,too

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
set PYTHONPATH="C:\Program Files (x86)\Quantum GIS Wroclaw\apps\qgis\bin"
```

The spaces ruin the path otherwise.

Comment: same error happen....