# How to call QGIS modules (qgis.core) from python idle as I can call arcpy

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I was trying to set up path to be able to call  qgis  modules as it defined in their website Introduction and set PYTHONPATH=c:\qgispath\python .  I also try to follow suggestion in link below

[How to import qgis.core to python IDLE?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/42659/how-to-import-qgis-core-to-python-idle)

However, I still get import error.
I also get error ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

The other error I get is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import qgis.core
  File "C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\qgis\python\qgis\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    import sip
ImportError: No module named sip
```

I want to be able to call this module from Spider or Python idle under arcgis. Does anyone know how to do that or have more detailed explained documentation? I can call the arcpy from spider but I could not achieve that for  qgis.core module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I added Python Paths below:

```
'C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\Python27\sip'
'C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\qgis\python' 
'C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages'
```

The problem was solved in PyScripter, however in the Spider, the error is now changed to as below:

```
from qgis._core import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

I guess I will use PyScripter instead of Spider.

Comment: Download [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) and point it at `C:\Program Files\QGIS Wien\apps\qgis\python\qgis\_core.pyd` then post the results