# Processing algorithm fails from Python script

Tags: qgis, python, grass-gis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

I'm trying to write a Python script performing a geoalgorithm.
What is surprising me is the following:

1. I first test the algorithm by QGIS (2.8) interface. In my case, the GRASS interpolator v.surf.idw
2. I see that the solution is sufficiently good using a certain setting of parameters.
3. Then, I run the same algorithm with the same parameters, froma Python script. In my case:

   ```
   out_ras = processing.runalg("grass:v.surf.idw", vl,12,2,"field_3" ,False, "%f , %f, %f, %f "% (xmin , xmax , ymin , ymax), 0.5, -1, 0.001, fileoutput)
   ```

where:

- `vl` is the point vector layer
- `field_3` is the filed where vlaues to be interpolated
- `fileoutput` is the raster file in output
- `(xmin, , xmax , ymin , ymax)` are the Extent of my layer

This setting (perfectly working when launched from QGis interface) produices a Nodata value Raster (only 1 cell).
It seems that the algorithm does not recognize the vector in input.
I've also checked the CRS of the layer (with vl.crs().authid() ) and everything sounds good.

Any help?
Any experience in detecting different behaviour of the SAME algorithm run by Python through processing instead of from QGIS UI ?

Comment: Did you import the required QGIS modules? Is your PYTHONPATH set to the same python that QGIS uses or another installed version? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8922568/error-no-module-named-qgis and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22886/how-to-import-qgis-core-to-python-app

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @iaborsi! Could you please edit your question to include a snippet of code instead of a one-liner, such as a couple of terms which you needed to define and the imports you used as this could help potential answerers :)

Comment: I'd suggest you to validate that your point layer is correctly loaded, this way: `print vl.isValid()`, which should print `True`. Please tell us if that check is OK.

Comment: Thanks to all for your suggestion. However, the problem is not in loading module or layer. I paste below a snippet of the code.

Comment: from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *


import processing


# Define the data source

vl = iface.activeLayer()

if vl.isValid() :
    print 'Layer is valid!'


fileoutput = "C:\Users\iacopo.borsi\Desktop\rastout.tif"

ext = vl.extent()
xmin = ext.xMinimum()
ymin = ext.yMinimum()
xmax = ext.xMaximum()
ymax = ext.yMaximum()
myfield = 'Z'

Comment: out_ras = processing.runalg("grass:v.surf.idw", vl , 12 ,2.0, myfield ,False, "%f , %f, %f, %f "% (xmin , xmax , ymin , ymax), 20, -1, 0.001, fileoutput)

fileInfo = QFileInfo(fileoutput)
baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(fileoutput, baseName)

if rlayer.isValid():
    QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer( rlayer )
else:
     print 'Raster layer is not valid!'

Answer (score 2):

it seems that my problem was in the GRASS algorithm I was using.
Now, I've moved to GDAL algorithm named "Grid - InverseDistance To a Power" and it works.
I don't really know what was wrong: my only suspect is that after running grass algorithm I would need to "convert" the grass raster map created to a "readble" raster, to be loaded in QGis correctly. I realized such a guess after reading the processing log file and comparing the log obtained by python-based run with the one obtained after launching the process by the GUI.
But this is only a guess... hoping this could help some body else playing with GRASS and processing.