# GRASS 7 commands in PyQGIS without results (QGIS 2.18)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, grass-gis, qgis-processing

I have tried to run different GRASS commands as part of a PyQGIS script in QGIS 2.18 and 2.14, without obtaining any result, e.g. for the following code:

```
# Open raster
fileInfo = QFileInfo(raster)
baseName = fileInfo.baseName()
filePath = str(os.path.abspath(raster))
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer(filePath, baseName)

# Define raster extent
extent = rlayer.extent()
xmin = extent.xMinimum()
xmax = extent.xMaximum()
ymin = extent.yMinimum()
ymax = extent.yMaximum()

# Open vector
vector = QgsVectorLayer(vector, vector, "ogr")

# Break each line at each point shared between 2 and more lines
cleaned = "cleaned.shp"
processing.runalg('grass7:v.clean', {"input": vector, "tool": 8,
    "GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER": "%f,%f,%f,%f" % (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax),
    "output": cleaned})
```

This code doesn't throw any error (also not in the Log Message Panel > Processing). However, no output is generated and the file is not accessible with iface.addVectorLayer. I have tried different grass commands as well and running the script in the Python console of QGIS 2.14 and QGIS 2.16. A similar script works fine, if only qgis and no GRASS commands are used.

I am guessing that QGIS is not properly connected to the GRASS commands. I didn't have these problems with QGIS 2.16, which I don't have installed any more, so I didn't run this script in QGIS 2.16.

Here a related question on this question:
[Get results from using GRASS algorithms with the QGIS processing tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176071/get-results-from-using-grass-algorithms-with-the-qgis-processing-tool) --> Running QGIS as an administrator didn't change anything

Secondly, I am wondering if it would be advisable to switch from

- programming PyQGIS scripts, calling all processing modules via `processing.runalg()` and running these scripts in the QGIS Python shell to
- programming Python scripts that call modules e.g `grass.run_command` and running these in the OsGeo4W shell.

I don't have much experience on that second option and find it hard to estimate additional required knowledge. But from the few examples I am finding on my first option, I get the feeling that I am not using the most common approach. Any advice on this?

Comment: I might have come a little closer to understanding the problem.
The above problem still remains the same, but I thought this might help someone with more background knowledge on this to think of a solution:

Comment: When I launch QGIS, the following error message occurs in the Log Message Panel in the Processing tab:

`2017-02-08T17:01:23 2 Could not load provider: GRASS commands
 [...]
   NameError: global name 'Grass7Utils' is not defined`

Since in `GrassUtils.py` GRASS7 is not further mentionend, I removed the 7 in the script GrassUtils.py, I changed 'Grass7Utils' to 'GrassUtils':

`localPath = os.path.join(GrassUtils.grassPath(), 'docs/html')`

Now the error message above does not appear any more, when I launch QGIS.

Comment: Secondly, when I launch QGIS, the following error message occurs in the Log Message Panel in the Plugins tab:

`Failed to load C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/plugins/grassplugin6.dll (Reason: Cannot load library C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis/plugins/grassplugin6.dll: The specified module could not be found.)`
The same error appears for `grassprovider6.dll` and `grassrasterprovider6.dll`

Comment: All these files are in the specified folder. I reinstalled all GRASS related parts and QGIS 2.18 with the OSGeo4W installer, before doing all this. 
When I run one of the GRASS commands (not one of the GRASS GIS 7 commands) from the Processing Toolbox, I get the following error: `NameError: global name 'QUrl' is not defined`