# standalone script using grass7:v.clean gives erro

Tags: grass-7.0, ppygis

I am writing a standalone script using QGIS processing plugins. everything works but after adding a new command it gives me some errors. The command is as folloing:

```
processing.runalg("grass7:v.clean",
                BK3,
                2,
                dgarc,
                None,
                -1,
                0.0001,
                BK4,
                BKerror)
```

dgarc is a float number and is equal to 1.BK3 and BK4 are string and are correctly defined. many other processes working with the same strings. The error is as following:

Error: Wrong parameter value: None

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to specify the GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER  as extents, e.g.,

```
processing.runalg("grass7:v.clean",
            BK3,
            2,
            dgarc,
            "%f , %f, %f, %f "% (xmin , xmax , ymin , ymax),
            -1,
            0.0001,
            BK4,
            BKerror)
```

[This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176071/get-results-from-using-grass-algorithms-with-the-qgis-processing-tool) question had a similar issue.

Comment: There is no error during execution in command window but the results are not as it should be. for example the dangling arcs are not deletes. I use the sme variables in QGIS, there it works but in standalone script it does not work. I mean, it works but delivers wrong result better to say the shap-file is as same as before.