# GRASS 7 tools in QGIS results in EPSG:3397 (PD/83 GK4) instead of 31468 (DHDN GK4) causing dislocation

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, qgis-processing, grass-7.0

GRASS 7 tools used from QGIS produce a result in a projection differing from the input projection which might lead to inconsistences:

Example `v.net.connect`, input EPSG of both layers is 31468 (DHDN GK4):

[image]

Result is in EPSG:3397 (PD/83 GK4):

[image]

Same with `v.clean`.

The resulting network is located ~1.5m away from the original, which is of course unacceptable (blue: original network, red: result after `v.clean` rsp. `v.net.connect`):

[image]

Why this unauthorized change of coordinate system and how to force GRASS 7 tools executed from QGIS (2.18.16) to output results in the same CRS as the inputs?

**UPDATE**

Trying the same in QGIS 2.99.0-280 leads to the same change in CRS, but *does not* cause erroneous dislocation of the data:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's good news that in 2.18.17 I did not observe the above mentioned dislocation.

Assume you are using GRASS 7 algorithms from either *graphical modeler* or with *PyQGIS processing module* you can do a reproject right after the GRASS 7 algorithm

in the graphical modeler:

[image]

[image]

in PyQGIS sth. like:

```
import processing
root = QgsProject.instance().layerTreeRoot()
input_layer = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayersByName('TheInputLayer')[0]
clean = processing.runalg('grass7:v.clean', network_layer, 0, 0.1, region, -1, 0.0001, None, None)
clean_repr = processing.runalg('qgis:reprojectlayer', clean['output'], 'EPSG:31468', None)
clean_repr_lyr = QgsVectorLayer(clean_repr['OUTPUT'], 'result_31468', 'ogr')
root.addLayer(clean_repr_lyr)
```

...where `region` is a grass region extent like described in the answer to [Get results from using GRASS algorithms with the QGIS processing tool](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176071/get-results-from-using-grass-algorithms-with-the-qgis-processing-tool)

In the layer properties you can see that the result is now in 'EPSG:31468'

Answer (score 4):

EPSG:31468 and EPSG:3397 share the same projection parameters, but differ in the datum. The first has `towgs84` parameters, while the second does not.

Your output is a shapefile, and the shapefile projection definition does not care about datum shifts nor EPSG codes. So QGIS has to guess, and selects the wrong one.

Try `Set Layer CRS` to get it back to the right one, or select a different file format that cares about shift parameters and EPSG codes, like spatialite.

Or do all your work in WGS84-based coordinate systems like ETRS89 UTM (what I prefer by now).