# Getting results from processing.run GRASS r.resample in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, grass-gis, qgis-3

I am trying to get output from r.resample in a stand-alone PYQGIS application. The code runs and does not show any errors, but it does not save an output file (i.e. 'c:/path/to/output.tif'). As far as I can tell, I have set GRASS up ok. I can run the same code through the QGIS console and get a result.

I found a possible answer [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176071/get-results-from-using-grass-algorithms-with-the-qgis-processing-tool), saying that it might be because grass commands need an extent. However, I tried that (see code below) and the command still does not run.

I am using Windows 10, Python 3.7 and QGIS 3.6.

What is the reason it is not producing an output raster?

```
from sys import argv
import os, sys, time, csv, ogr,subprocess
from osgeo import ogr

# GRASS7 set-up ################################
gisdb = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "grassdata")
if sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    # MS Windows
    grass7bin = r'C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\grass76.bat'
# query GRASS GIS itself for its GISBASE
startcmd = [grass7bin, '--config', 'path']
try:
    p = subprocess.Popen(startcmd, shell=False,
                         stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = p.communicate()
except OSError as error:
    sys.exit("ERROR: Cannot find GRASS GIS start script"
             " {cmd}: {error}".format(cmd=startcmd[0], error=error))
if p.returncode != 0:
    sys.exit("ERROR: Issues running GRASS GIS start script"
             " {cmd}: {error}"
             .format(cmd=' '.join(startcmd), error=err))
out2 = out.decode("utf-8")

gisbase = out2.strip(os.linesep)
print("GIS base: ",gisbase)
os.environ['GISBASE'] = gisbase
# define GRASS-Python environment
grass_pydir = os.path.join(gisbase, "etc", "python")
sys.path.append(grass_pydir)
# GRASS7 set-up complete #########################

app = QgsApplication([], False)   # second argument to False disables the GUI
app.initQgis()
# start processing
import processing
from processing import Processing
Processing.initialize()

#### r.resample starts here ####################
raster_source = path/to/raster.tif
rlay = QgsRasterLayer(raster_source, "raster_name", "gdal")
if not rlay.isValid():
    print("Layer failed to load!") # layer is valid

ext = rlay.extent()
xmin = ext.xMinimum()
xmax = ext.xMaximum()
ymin = ext.yMinimum()
ymax = ext.yMaximum()
coords = "%f,%f,%f,%f" %(xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

# You can see what parameters are needed by the algorithm
# using: processing.algorithmHelp("grass7:r.resample")
 params = {
     'input' : rlay,
     'output' : 'c:/path/to/output.tif',
     'GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER':coords,
     'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER':200,
     'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT':'',
     'GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META':''
                    }

res = processing.run("grass7:r.resample", params)
## Process runs but no output is saved
```

---

Edit: some commands output the final file, but not all do. For example, `gdal:proximity` also does not provide an output.

Comment: Before app.initQgis() `QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/path/to/QGIS", True)` should be called, where /pat/to/QGIS is `os.path.join(os.getenv("OSGEO4W_ROOT"), "apps\\qgis")` under windows. Don't know if that solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Spent 4 hours to find out that some GRASS algorithms will not work if the file path contains Cyrillic characters. So use only english in the path. Perhaps this will help someone.