# import error of qgis.core even though PYTHONPATH set up with system environment variable

Tags: pyqgis, import, windows-7, environment-variable

I made the environment variables as described here: [How2 Import](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22886/how-to-import-qgis-core-to-python-app) 
Though I still receive this error:

```
C:\>python
Python 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import qgis.core
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\qgis\__init__.py", line 27, in      <module>
from qgis.core import QgsFeature, QgsGeometry
File "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\qgis\core\__init__.py", line 30, in <module>
from qgis._core import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: Det angivne modul blev ikke fundet.
 >>>
```

This is my environment PYTHONPATH string:

```
 C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\include;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python\qgis\core;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\bin\qgis_core.dll;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\bin;C:\Program Files\QGIS Essen\bin\qgis.bat;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\Python27\Lib\site-packages;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-rel-dev\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\bin;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\python;C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis-dev\bin
```

As I have checked, "qgis_core.dll" is located in "C:\OSGeo4W64\apps\qgis\bin" which is the first variable.

[Edit]
I installed Qgis 2.16 through OSGeo4W

Comment: Perhaps the answer to this post might help: [Problem with import qgis.core when writing a stand-alone PyQGIS script](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129959/problem-with-import-qgis-core-when-writing-a-stand-alone-pyqgis-script/130102#130102)