# qgis.core import to Python 3

Tags: qgis, python, environment-variable

I had a pure Python 3 configured for myself and recently installed QGIS (just QGIS, not OSGeo4W). 
I need to keep my initial Python 3 but also add `qgis.core` module. 
Can it be done with no harm to my previously installed Python? 
I saw that installing OSGeo4W [should help](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/22887/77806) but anyway there is some paths need to set in the user environment settings.

Comment: Nothing to worry about.